# LINQ operations on IDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Let's suppose I have the following dictionaries:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
      { 1, "a" },
      { 2, "b" },
      { 3, "c" }
}

private Dictionary<SomeEnum, bool> dic2 = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, bool>()
{
      { SomeEnum.First, true },
      { SomeEnum.Second, false },
      { SomeEnum.Third, false }
}
```

I want to convert these two dictionaries into a `Dictionary<string, object>`

For example:

```
 dic1 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
     { "1", "a" },
     { "2", "b" },
     { "3", "c" }
 }

 dic2 = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
     { "First", true },
     { "Second", false },
     { "Third", false }
 }
```

As you can see, the `string` key of these dictionaries is just the `string` representation of the previous ones.

The method that is responsible for the conversion has the following signature:

```
 public static object MapToValidType(Type type, object value)
 {
     //....

     if(typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(type))
     {
         //I have to return a Dictionary<string, object> here
         return ??;
     }
 }
```

I have tried the following:

```
 ((IDictionary)value).Cast<object>().ToDictionary(i => ...);
```

But `i` was casted to an object, so I cannot access the key or value items. For that I would need to cast it to the appropiate `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, but I don't know `TKey` or `TValue` type.

Another solution is to do this:

```
IDictionary dic = (IDictionary)value;
IList<string> keys = dic.Keys.Cast<object>().Select(k => Convert.ToString(k)).ToList();
IList<object> values = dic.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
Dictionary<string, object> newDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
for(int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
   newDic.Add(keys[0], values[0]);
return newDic;
```

However, I'm not much of a fan of this approach and I am really looking for a simpler and friendlier one line LINQ statement.

Comment: Have a look at my answer is that what you need, convert any generic dictionary to Dictionary<string, object>, simple two operations, one line, method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this, no LINQ though, i think you don't need:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> ConvertToDictionary(System.Collections.IDictionary iDic) {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var enumerator = iDic.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                dic[enumerator.Key.ToString()] = enumerator.Value;
            }
        return dic;
    }
```

Or a Linq one:

```
return iDic.Keys.Cast<object>().ToDictionary(k=> k.ToString(), v=> iDic[v]);
```

Comment: Simpler than my approach, but I must not lose hope for a LINQ alternative

Comment: Way to go! That single LINQ line worked as expected!

Comment: Note the first one is faster than the second because the second re-hits the dictionary for each key/value pair with `iDic[v]`.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to cast your IDictionary to a generic type of DictionaryEntry. Then you can use ToDictionary() from System.Linq.

```
static Dictionary<string,object> ToDictionary(IDictionary dic)
{
    return dic.Cast<DictionaryEntry> ().ToDictionary ((t) => t.Key.ToString (), (t) => t.Value);
}
```

Comment: This only works if `IDictionary` is for example a `Hashtable`. But if `IDictionary` is in fact a `Dictionary<string, object>()`, it will throw a System.InvalidCastException.

Comment: The [documentation for IDictionary.Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-idictionary-values?view=net-7.0) says "note that the enumerator for the System.Collections.IDictionary interface returns DictionaryEntry objects rather than KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> objects."

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var blah = KeyToString(dic1);

        // Verify that we converted correctly
        foreach (var kvp in blah)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, {2} {3}", kvp.Key.GetType(), kvp.Key, kvp.Value.GetType(), kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    static Dictionary<string, TValue> KeyToString<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> dic1)
    {
        return dic1.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp => kvp.Value);
    }
```

Comment: I am working with `IDictionary`, how can I use your method?

Comment: Edited to use more general `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, which `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements

Comment: I probably confused you. I am using [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with no generics. [IDictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is another type

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> Convert<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> genDictionary)
{
    return genDictionary.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(kvp.Key.ToString(), (object)kvp.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

called like:

```
    var dicIntInt = new Dictionary<int, string>{{123, "asdc"}, {456, "aa"} };

    Dictionary<string, object> dicStrObj = Convert(dicIntInt);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eY41MQ

Comment: I wish it was this easy, but `d1` is of type `IDictionary` in my case, therefore I cannot apply LINQ queries on it

Comment: I'm working with `IDictionary` (non generic) type, yet your `Convert` method takes a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which is a completely different class (and it uses generics)

Comment: No, it takes a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [IDictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are two different types

Comment: Sorry my bad, getting the enumerator and lopping through best option with this interface (@George answer)